# can i use Azure Signalr on .net 4.5.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, .net-framework-version, azure-signalr

I have a .NET 4.5.2 app that uses SignalR to call a device and ask it to perform a certain action. I want to switch and use Azure SignalR. Is there any way to do this? The Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet library that I need to set the connection string is not compatible with my .NET version (4.5.2).

Comment: [4.5.2 went out of support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) so NuGet packages are no longer required to support it either. The earliest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2

Comment: One of the reasons NuGet authors dropped support for 4.5.2 so quickly is that it really didn't work well with .NET Standard 2.0, requiring a lot of compatibility libraries that often conflicted with each other. 4.6.2 supports .NET Standard 2.0 natively so there are no conflicts

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find a version on [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet), but the latest requires .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Aside, you should also consider upgrading to .NET Framework 4.8. It should be a drop in replacement.